# How to disable button using props in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js. I am trying to disable button using props value. This is how I am trying to do but its not working throwing an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."`. Is it the correct way to do this? Please help me. Thanks

```
import React from "react";

function Note(props) {

  function handleClickUpdateA() {
    props.onUpdateA(props.id);
  }

  var dis;

  if(props.des === '1')
  {
    dis = 'disabled';
  } else
  {
    dis = ' ';
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <button {dis} onClick={handleClickUpdateA}>Accept</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Note;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` element gets a `disabled` prop. You can set it `true` for disabling it. And `false` to able it. So you just need to change your `jsx` like below.

JSX Part:

```
<button disabled={dis === 'disabled'} onClick={handleClickUpdateA}>Accept</button>
```

---

But I recommed to use a `isDisabled` variable and set that to `true` or `false` instead of `dis` with string value. It is a best practice I think.

So your code would become like this:

JS Part:

```js
var isDisabled = props.des === '1' ? true : false;
```

JSX Part:

```
<button disabled={isDisabled} onClick={handleClickUpdateA}>Accept</button>
```

It is more readable now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check whether the button is active or not.

```
 import React from "react";

    function Note(props) {

      function handleClickUpdateA() {
        props.onUpdateA(props.id);
      }

      var dis;

      if(props.des === '1')
      {
        dis = 'disabled';
      } else
      {
        dis = ' ';
      }

      return (

        <div>
          <p>{props.content}</p>
          <button 
          disabled = { props.des === 1 ? true : false  //Your props coming here. and you can return true or false based on the value that comes with props. in this case you will not need to install the if else structure above}
         />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Note;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
function Note(props) {
  function handleClickUpdateA() {
    props.onUpdateA(props.id);
  }
  var dis;

  if(props.des === '1')
  {
    dis = true';
  } else
  {
    dis = false;
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <button disabled={dis} onClick={handleClickUpdateA}>Accept</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Note;
```